# What are the likely consequences to Uganda after the passage of its anti-gay law?

Tags: human-rights

The president of Uganda, [Kaguta Yoweri Museveni](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoweri_Museveni) on 24th of February, [signed in a new law](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-africa-26320102) whereby a gay person will be jailed for 14 years and if caught on committing the crime on a second instance they will serve a life imprisonment.

This was criticized by [Obama who warned](http://www.cnn.com/2014/02/24/world/africa/uganda-anti-gay-bill/) that the U.S might no longer give any donations to the republic of Uganda. Kaguta signed the bill into law and cited that he can trade with the East because they don't interfere with his country's internal affairs. Kaguta said that homosexual acts are unnatural, unafrican and wondered why "somebody would leave something good for something bad"

- **Will the U.S stop it's donation to Uganda?**

In Kenya, we support anti-homosexual legislation, but soon it might be tabled upon the parliament floor.

Comment: I have edited your question. In general, we don't allow questions that ask for a persons motivations (The only one who can answer would be the person about whom you are asking). We also don't deal with moral right/wrongs. I left the only question that can have an objective answer.

Comment: Even edited, I'm not sure how this question is answerable beyond Obama's warning.

Comment: The deep record of promises kept by Obama administration points to unequivocal "yes" answer to the bolded question. Witness what happened when Al-Assad's forces crossed the "red line" of using chemical weapons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes. I have just learnt that world bank has suspended $90 million loan for Uganda because of the anti gay legislature .

Comment: A link would help...